# LookBehind - Find string occuring after a pattern

Tags: regex, lookbehind

I need help regarding a regex Query :-

```
C: - total 79.45 Gb - used: 33.82 Gb (43%) - free 45.63 Gb (57%)
```

This is my sample text . I want to find the %usage of used disk . i.e 43% in my case .
I am using lookbehind to find the occurrences after "used" keyword .
This is the pattern i am using `(?<=(\bused))(.*?\(\d*%\))` . But this is giving me `: 33.82 Gb (43%)` as the output . I only need 43 as my output.
Can anyone please help

Comment: Is that `df` output? What tool are you using?

Comment: which program do you use to match the pattern and get its result?

Comment: If you are using a GNU grep, try `grep -Po '\bused:[^(]*\(\K\d+'`

Comment: i am using a online tool https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capturing only the `\d*` part:

```
(\bused)(.*?\((\d*)%\))
              *   *
```

The asterisks are where the group 3, the group you want, starts and ends.

Or you can make every other group non capturing, and get group 1:

```
(?:\bused)(?:.*?\((\d*)%\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFvMfY/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using python3 you can write this :

```
import re
re_findall = re.findall("used:.*\(([0-9]*)%\) -",line)
```

where line is :

```
C: - total 79.45 Gb - used: 33.82 Gb (43%) - free 45.63 Gb (57%)
```

This is similar to what Sweeper say, you just only "capture" the number here using a python module.